# How to fix this AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, append, attributeerror

This is my code:

```
m1=int(input("¿Cuantas filas tiene la matriz 1?: "))
contador_filas1=1
f1=[]
while contador_filas1<=m1:
  print("Dame los valores de la fila",contador_filas1,"(separados por comas):")
  f1.append=input()
  contador_filas1=contador_filas1+1
print(filas1)
```

What can I do? If I want to do a list, with the values given by `f1.append`
but when I run the program the shell is launching me this notice:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Susana\Desktop\Matrices.py", line 10, in <module>
   f1.append=input()
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass the result of `input` as argument to `append`

`f1.append(input())`

Comment: thank you very much! i did it few seconds i posted the question, and it works.
:D